# Get current page path from react-routers browserHistory object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Outside of my components I need to query the current active URL. I'm going to set some classes on the body ( which is outside my react root ) based on this.

First attempt was to use

```
//Gets an array of class names that I can add to my body tag
getClassNames(window.location.pathname);
```

But it seems window.location.path **isn't updated** when React Router navigates. Surprising yes.

So I thought, ok maybe I can get this from browserHistory

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
```

But alas, I can't see a way to read the current page path from here either ( no decent API documentation seems to exist for this object)

Any tips?  Seems like a simple problem, and it would be if window.location.pathname stayed in sync with the history object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok as of 2017 at least, location is available via

`browserHistory.getCurrentLocation();`

```
const location = browserHistory.getCurrentLocation();
console.log(location);
```

Comment: In react-router@3.2.0 should call `location.pathname`

Answer (score 7):

The only way I know to do this right now is to use a listener like

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
browserHistory.listen(function(event) {
    //manage the pathname on your own
    console.log(event.pathname);
});
```

Not ideal, but even after looking at the DOMUtils library used by history, its implementation of getWindowPath() includes the pathname, search, and hash strings.  However, looking for a docs link for you on GitHub, History seems to have received a v3 rewrite as of ~20 days ago and now includes a [pathUtils module](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/modules/PathUtils.js) that may be useful to you.

Comment: what about router v4 ?